# Using Python, is there a way to query an xarray Dataset using a separate variable?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am trying to query an xarray Dataset using another variable. I've seen examples of querying a Dataset using specific values, but I'd like to know if there is a way to replace the value with a variable name.

For example, this works fine:

```
a = np.arange(0, 5, 1)
b = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)
ds = xr.Dataset({"a": ("x", a), "b": ("x", b)})
ds.query(x="a > 2")
```

But I'd like to do something like

```
z = 2
ds.query(x="a > z")
```

This query returns the error message:

> UndefinedVariableError: name 'z' is not defined

In Pandas, I could use `@z` in a query, but when I try `ds.query(x="a > @z")`, I get

> SyntaxError: The '@' prefix is not allowed in top-level eval calls.
> please refer to your variables by name without the '@' prefix.

Is there a way to query an xarray Dataset using a separate variable? The value I am querying by would change depending on certain conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xarray, you can use the sel method to query a Dataset using a variable rather than a specific value. You can define your condition using the variable z and then use it with the sel method to filter the Dataset.

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr


a = np.arange(0, 5, 1)
b = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)
ds = xr.Dataset({"a": ("x", a), "b": ("x", b)})


z = 2

# Use the sel method to filter the Dataset based on the condition
filtered_ds = ds.sel(x=ds['a'] > z)


print(filtered_ds)
```

z is a variable representing the condition you want to apply. We use the sel method to select the elements of the Dataset where the condition ds['a'] > z is met. This will give you a new Dataset, filtered_ds, that contains the elements of ds where the condition is true.

Comment: That is great, thank you. So if I wanted to select by an additional condition, e.g., `y = 4` and I wanted `ds['a'] > z` and `ds['a'] < y`. Is there an easy method to do that?

Comment: @KAR you can use the & operator to combine the conditions.

Comment: filtered_ds = ds.sel(x=(ds['a'] > z) & (ds['a'] < y))